# Position operator acting on position

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, eigenvalue

I'm trying to prepare for an exam facing the following task:

$\fbox{$\textsf{calculate matrix-elements $\quad\langle r|\hat{r}^2|r'\rangle\quad$ for any state $\quad|r\rangle, \quad |r'\rangle$}\quad$}$

I'm not entirely sure how to tackle this:

I would claim the following eigenvalue equation are true:

$\hat{r}|r\rangle = r|r\rangle \quad $and $ \quad \hat{r}|r'\rangle = r'|r'\rangle$

But using this properties I'd get something like $\quad\langle r|\hat{r}^2|r'\rangle = \langle r|r'^2|r'\rangle$

And I think it is weird. How is it related to matrix elements?

Comment: Hint: Since $r'^2$ is a number it can be taken outside the braket. Then evaluate the braket.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’re almost there, since $r’$ is a number, you can factor it out. Using the generalized orthonormality relation: $\langle r|r’\rangle =\delta(r-r’)$, you get:
$$
\langle r|\hat r^2|r’\rangle =r’^2 \delta(r-r’)
$$
Note that if you had applied the operator to the bra or applied the left to the bra and the right to the ket, you would have obtained the seemingly different results: $r^2 \delta(r-r’)$ and $r r’ \delta(r-r’)$ respectively. Thankfully, thanks to the delta, $r=r’$, so the three expressions are therefore identical.

This is formally the matrix element of $\hat r^2$ in the position basis $|r\rangle$. The delta indicates that it is diagonal, which is expected since the basis is an eigenbasis of $\hat r$ by definition. Mathematically, you should not take it too literally as technically the position basis does not even lie in the Hilbert space and $\hat r^2$ is only densely defined on it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It does thanks for the extensive clarification!